# Do QBFT of quorum mine empty blocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, quorum, raft, qbft

We are currently using RAFT as the consensus protocol as it has the highest TPS, fastest block creation, and no empty block creation. However, recently GoQuorum tutorials highlighted not to use RAFT for production environment.

It is recommended to use QBFT. In this regard I want to know what is the TPS with QBFT, does QBFT mine empty blocks (we don't want empty blocks as it would add mining CPU to server)

Also can we switch the RAFT chain to QBFT or do we need to start a new chain?

Some insights on this will be of great help for us

Regards,
Mannoj

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with QBFT empty blocks are generated.

This is on purpose as it allows to check the state of the chaine and of the validators. Otherwise you can't tell if the chain is down or of there's just no transactions.

See https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/HowTo/Configure/Consensus-Protocols/QBFT/ and https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/latest/concepts/consensus/comparing-poa/ for more details on QBFT.

Comment: QBFT Empty block period is now supported as of 22.7

https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/configure-and-manage/configure/consensus-protocols/qbft#configure-empty-block-period